# Problems with encoding Json request

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, http-headers, mootools

I try to manually build a Json string to send to the client.

```
{'result':'hhh'}
```

When I use

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'hhh'));
```

It arrives perfectly.
But when I do

```
echo "{'result':'hhh'}";
```

It isn't

The only difference I find between the two requests is that the first one has:

```
Content-Length: 9    header
```

and the second one (which does not work)

```
Content-Length: 16   header
```

Both the strings should have been content length: 16!!! I guess it something to do with the combination of ZF and Mootools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the specs, JSON requires double quotes around key names and string values.

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'hhh'));
```

will output

```
{"result":"hhh"}
```

The length of this output is 16 bytes as shown by the following:

```
echo strlen(json_encode(array('result'=>'hhh')));
```

outputs "16".

Any JSON decoder that follows the specs will fail or throw an exception when presented with your manually echoed JSON.

Comment: If you will count the characters on my manually string, you will see the problem is something else completely. I need to investigate more, it seems something to do with the combination of ZF and Mootools

Comment: Just did some testing and Elmo is correct.  You have to use double quotes, although I did not get an error trying to decode single quotes it was returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have *problems* with UTF-8 so much as UTF-8 is the standard encoding for it.  It sounds as if you're echoing something in a different encoding scheme, which breaks, whereas json_encode() is transcoding it for you.